# Invalidating locally cached data from an API in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

In an app I'm building, I'm using Core Data to cache remote content from an API for offline viewing. This all works pretty well except for one big issue: if a record on the server is deleted there's no way for me to detect that and delete its cached counterpart.

The only thing I can think of is somehow marking all the current data as 'invalid' when I pull data from the API and only mark the records returned by the API as valid again, but it seems like this is a clunky solution to the problem. Additionally, as data from the API I'm using is paginated it doesn't scale well for lots of records.

So what I want to know is: is there a better way to invalidate local cache data in response to it being deleted server-side?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest, although not the easiest route, is to have the server side cache items that are deleted and expose an endpoint you can call to get the deleted items. In a perfect world right.

What you can do is in a background thread, download all the data from the server and compare it to what you have locally. So instead of just invalidating all of it and re-parsing it back in (which can take time for large data sets), just run through and compare id's of objects on the server to your objects in CoreData. If it's there great, if not delete it from you local db. Hope this helps.

Comment: This would be the ideal solution for sure. Unfortunately in this case I'm working with a third-party API so I don't have any control over the implementation.

Comment: So just do the second part :)